# R logistic regression with a saturation level

Tags: r, logistic-regression, estimation

I would like to estimate a weighted model that is almost logistic but has a saturation level (S) that needs to be estimated. At the moment I am using a generic non-linear optimisation approach, along the lines of:

```
nls.model <- y ~ S/(1 + exp(-1 * (b1*x1+b2*x2+b3*x3)))
...
nlsGR.out <- nls(nls.model, data=x, start=nls.init.values, trace=F, weight=weight, control=nls.ctrl)
```

Where S is the saturation that I am interested in. y is a double in the range [0.0,1.0]

I wonder if there is a more efficient, robust or just appropriate package routine I can use?

Comment: I think `nlme::gnls` with the `params` argument and `SSfpl` might be the pieces you need.  Reproducible example?